# Nginx set location for php script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a Rails app and want to set an URL for a php application.

The Rails app works on standard rails settings in var/www/myapp. There is also var/www/myapp/public which is a root directory for domain.

```
www.mysite.com // have root in var/www/myapp/public
```

And then I want to have admin for other php application in:

```
www.mysite.com/myphpapp/admin // so aplication is in var/www/myapp/public/myphpapp/admin
```

Right now I'm trying to set:

```
location myphpapp/admin{

  //and what goes here?
}
```

Whatever I put inside location I always have 404 not found or file not found. I try to do it like for location for phpmyadmin but it does not work.

Comment: actually the php app should be in `/var/www/myphpapp/admin`, or is it an admin interface for the rails app ?

Comment: thanks but i make it work right now. No it is admin for other php app